# Exposing data models as graphql api with filters

Tags: web-applications, backend, graphql

I've been playing with `GraphQL` for a while now, using both `graphql-js` (javascript) and `graphene` (python).
GraphQL comes with relay spec for pagination, which is awesome for our schema.
But I find it hard to set my mind on the filters.

Every database provides a full query language (whether it is SQL or NoSQL).
For our simple web apps, all we need is access to our data, all of the interesting stuff happens in the client side thanks to rich js frameworks.

So after reviewing a few of our backend apps, all I can see is parsers:
parsing requests from `REST` to `MongoDB` or `SQL`.

We try to provide rich queries to the client side, so we add arguments to our `graphql` endpoints,
but every new filter requires a lot of work (new code).

Going from `REST` to `GraphQL` is great,
but why not take it a little farther with a more expressive language for data querying?
Is there a reason for those restrictions?
Should we keep develop "parsers"?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a point you made above, the GraphQL spec does not include Relay and mentions nothing about pagination. In fact, GraphQL doesn't specify a network layer either so the choice to use HTTP is up to the implementor.

So what does GraphQL provide:

- A strong type system defining the shape and relationships of data
- A query language for requesting parts of that data

You seem to be asking why GraphQL doesn't make that query language more expressive and the answer to that is that, for the most part, GraphQL is unconcerned both with how data is retrieved from data sources like SQL or REST clients and with how data is returned to the end-user.

It's also worth noting that performant query optimization is a huge area of study and, in things like SQL are tuned to the underlying mechanisms for accessing the data. It's likely that some of the reasons to leave this out have to do with leaving the data-store up to the implementor.